# Ошибка использования пространства имен

Tags: c++

В чем может быть ошибка?

```
std::cout << (float)5/8 << std:endl;
```

> error C2882: 'std' : illegal use of namespace identifier in expression

Answer (score 5):

Всё предельно просто - второе двоеточие пропустил.

Comment: Поддержу. А еще оказалось, что `std::endl` можно не добавлять и часто вместо него использовать `"\n"`. Хотя отличие лишь в двух моментах - `std::endl` более портабельный вариант и оно скидывает буфер `cout`'а.

Comment: @gecube И потому куда более медленный...

Answer (score 0):

В общем, лучше всего подключать пространство имен `std` в начале программы:

```
using namespace std;
```

Comment: Использовать "using namespace <название namespace>;" не рекомендуется, так как это засоряет глобальное пространство имен.

Comment: @Андрей,если используется только одно пространство, то Ваш комментарий лишний, ведь не всякому удобно писать каждый раз std::, особенно если этих разов в коде огого сколько, знаю по опыту.